# Objective-c pendulum modelling memory issues

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, simulation

I am trying to implement a modelling class for a Physics project with finite difference methods for simulating a simple pendulum. I want to be able to make this class as generic as possible so I can do whatever I want with the values on each iteration of the method. For this reason I have given my methods callback blocks which can also be used to stop the method if we want to.

For example my Euler method loop looks like so:

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    if (callBack) {
        if(!callBack(NO, currentTheta, currentThetaDot, currentT, (CGFloat)i/n)) break;
    }

    currentTheta += self.dt*f_single_theta(currentThetaDot);
    currentThetaDot += self.dt*f_single_thetaDot(currentTheta, currentThetaDot, gamma);

    currentT += self.dt;

}
```

And in the callBack block I run the code

```
^BOOL (BOOL complete, double theta, double thetaDot, CGFloat timeElapsed, CGFloat percentComplete){

    eulerT = [eulerT stringByAppendingFormat:@"%.8f\n",timeElapsed];
    eulerTheta = [eulerTheta stringByAppendingFormat:@"%.8f\n",theta];

    if ((currentThetaDot*currentThetaDot + cos(currentTheta)) > 0.5) {
        return 0; // stops running if total E > 0.5
    }        

    return 1;

}];
```

Where eulerT and eulerTheta are strings which I later save to a file. This callback method quickly results in a massive build up of memory, even for n of order 10,000 I end up with about 1Gb of RAM usage. As soon as I comment out calling the `callBack` block this drops right off. Is there anyway I can keep this nice functionality without the massive memory problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people who are new to Objective C do not realize the difference between `[NSArray array]` and `[[NSArray alloc] init]`. In the days before ARC, the difference was much more obvious now. Both create a new object, but the former allocates the object, assigns it to the current `NSAutoreleasePool`, and leaves it with a retain count of 0 while the latter allocates it and leaves it with a retain count of 1.

Objects that are assigned to an `NSAutoreleasePool` do not get deallocated immediately when the retain count reaches 0. Instead, they get deallocated when the OS gets time to. Generally this can be assumed to be when control returns to the current run loop, but it can also be when `drain` is called on the `NSAutoreleasePool`.

With ARC, the difference is less obvious, but still significant. Many, if not most, of the objects your allocate are assigned to an autorelease pool. This means that you don't get them back just because you're done using them. That leads to the memory usage spiking in tight loops, such as what you posted. The solution is to explicitly drain your autorelease pool, like this:

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    if (callBack) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            if(!callBack(NO, currentTheta, currentThetaDot, currentT, (CGFloat)i/n))
                break;
        }
    }

    currentTheta += self.dt*f_single_theta(currentThetaDot);
    currentThetaDot += self.dt*f_single_thetaDot(currentTheta, currentThetaDot, gamma);

    currentT += self.dt;

}
```

Comment: Nice answer. One nitpick: the ref count for e.g., `[NSArray array]` is _net_ 0, for _your_ code. It's actually owned by the autorelease pool and must have a non-zero absolute count in order to be alive at all. Of course, the net count for one's own code is all one should be considering anyways.

Comment: That's correct, but I didn't want to cover retains outside the developer's code.

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap the inside of your loop in @autoreleasepool{} to clean up temporary objects.